# iisnode not able to access file present in network file path

Tags: node.js, iis, fs, iisnode

[image]I am node app through iisnode. I can access file present in network path but when the application tries to access the file, it complains ' File doesn't exist'.

I tried adding IIS_IUSRS user group to have access to  iisnode www directory in my local machine. I changed the username(from application pool) of the application to which I have permission(R/W) on the network path. Restarted my machine. But still problem persist.

Can someone help me if there is issue between iisnode and network file path.

```
const csv=require('csvtojson');  
function fetchFile(){
sUsagefile ="\\\\abc\\xyz\\com.csv" .
 csv().fromFile(sUsagefile));  
 console.log(sUsagefile);
}

Error: File does not exist. Check to make sure the file path to your csv is correct.
    at C:\iisnode\www\node_modules\csvtojson\v2\Converter.js:81:37
    at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:312:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to access UNC path with iisnode and it was working perfectly.
Have you tried to grant IUSR and IIS Apppool\ read/writepermission for network path \abc\xyz\com.csv directly?

Besides, have you checked whether \abc\xyz\com.csv can be accessed from file explorer when IIS stop working.

It is suggested to use process monitor tool to monitor what path is read by node.exe. Please download process monitor from here:https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/procmon then add a filter like “Path contains com.csv". Finally we would know what path the application is trying to read.

Comment: I have added R/W permission in the remote location where file is residing. From the windows I am able to access the file. I am not sure how to grant permission that particular path inside IIS.

Comment: Try process monitor. It will tell us who and where is the R/W permission should be granted

Comment: I have downloaded procmon, tried creating filter based on process name but I am not sure what is the process name of iisnode ( I see node.exe and w3wp.exe)

Comment: I was able to create filter by file path I see the results to be success, buffer overflow, is directory, INVALID PARAMETER, NOT REPARSE POINT

Comment: I have added picture of process monitor after I tried to access the file

Comment: Hi have you tried to change both application pool and IIS pass-through user to a specific user who has permission to access the UNC path?