# Access the UNC path from javascript

Tags: javascript, fs, unc

I want to access the UNC path from javascript code. I am not sure the format in which UNC path  must be specified in the code.

I tried using

file://machine1/withPermission/abc.csv

\\machine1\withPermission\abc.csv

\machine1\withPermission\abc.csv

For all the try, I got file existence check to be false though I can access file from windows explorer.

{ Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, scandir '\machine1\withPermission\'
  errno: -4048,
  code: 'EPERM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '\\machine1\withPermission\' }
false //file existence

Comment: Sounds like you're not escaping your backslashes in a string literal. We'd have to know a **lot** more about the environment (Node.js? you've tagged [tag:fs] but...), and see the real code, in order to help.

Comment: yes it is node.js

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure the format in which UNC path must be specified in the code.

If the path you can access in Windows Explorer is `\\machine1\withPermission\abc.csv`, then that's the format to use with `fs`. You need to be sure to escape the backslashes if this is in a string or template literal, e.g.:

```
fs.someMethod("\\\\machine1\\withPermission\\abc.csv", function(err, result) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: I am able to access the file from win explorer through \\machine1\withPermission\abc.csv and inside code  using \\\\machine1\\withPermission\\abc.csv I am told permission deniec and file existence returns false

Comment: @karansys - Don't know what to tell you. If I do that, on a Windows machine with Node v8.11.1, it correctly accesses the file.

Comment: I  do  see you have logic ,  in ref this to this question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807014/iisnode-not-able-to-access-file-present-in-network-file-path. I want to access UNC

Comment: I have  same permission both the  ends

Comment: @karansys - Sorry, I don't understand what you mean there.

Comment: can you try to access UNC path from windows server, I am using windows server 2019

Comment: @karansys - I don't have Server 2019 handy. I wouldn't expect it to make a difference. If you can do (for instance) `dir \\machine1\withPermission\abc.csv` in `cmd.exe` and then in that same `cmd.exe` run your Node.js code, I would expect both of those to act the same.